# Spring Data Rest async calls

Tags: spring, rest

Is there a way to configure Spring Data Rest to allow non-blocking asynchronous calls?  Spring Rest provides @Async annotation to handle calls asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

@Async for method level and @EnableAsync is applicartion level.
As much i know this is way to handle the Async calls from spring boot application.

Answer (score 0):

Current, Spring Data Rest does not support ReactiveCrudRepository. This is the ticket open for it: [DATAREST-933](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-933)

But for a normal Controller/Service/Repository call, you have the following options:

**Non-Relational Databases:**

In order to use a non-blocking with Spring Data is using one of the following databases: MongoDB, Apache Cassandra and Redis, for example. They provide non-blocking drivers. [Going reactive with Spring Data](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/28/going-reactive-with-spring-data)

You also have to implement your repositories using **Mono** and **Flux** types, extending the interface **ReactiveCrudRepository**:

```
public interface ReactivePersonRepository
  extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Person, String> {

  Flux<Person> findByLastname(Mono<String> lastname);

  @Query("{ 'firstname': ?0, 'lastname': ?1}")
  Mono<Person> findByFirstnameAndLastname(String firstname, String lastname);
}
```

Here are more details of an example using MongoDB: [Reactive Repositories with MongoDB](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-reactive)

**Relational Databases**

Thanks to the module R2DBC, it is possible to use Reactive Repositories with SQL relational databases. [Documentation Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/#introduction)

> R2DBC is the acronym for Reactive Relational Database Connectivity.
>   R2DBC is an API specification initiative that declares a reactive API
>   to be implemented by driver vendors to access their relational
>   databases.

You can find more examples here: [Github Examples with R2DBC](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/r2dbc)
**Spring Framework Version:** 5.2.0.RELEASE

Dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>r2dbc-bom</artifactId>
      <version>${r2dbc-releasetrain.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

  <!-- other dependency elements omitted -->

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- a R2DBC driver -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
    <version>Arabba-RC1</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

These are the following drivers available:

- Postgres (io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql)
- H2 (io.r2dbc:r2dbc-h2)
- Microsoft SQL Server (io.r2dbc:r2dbc-mssql)
- MySQL (com.github.mirromutth:r2dbc-mysql)
- jasync-sql MySQL (com.github.jasync-sql:jasync-r2dbc-mysql)

This is an example of repository using **ReactiveCrudRepository** from the Github repository:

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;

/**
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 */
interface CustomerRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @Query("select id, firstname, lastname from customer c where c.lastname = :lastname")
    Flux<Customer> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```